# How to force an application to use a specific cpu?

Tags: linux, command-line, application

For example : To build a kernel we can use `make` it will take more than one hour , to accelerate the process we can use `make -j4 all` this may finish almost four times as quickly.

Generally : How to force an application to use a specific nombre `n`of cpu ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no general solution to this problem - cpu usage of applications is entirely down to what the application does, and how it works internally.

In order to parallelism tasks for efficiency reasons, you often need to restructure the process flow. This varies greatly, depending on algorithm, so it's never as simple as pressing a 'use more processors' button.